# Rails 4 paperclip hash value displayed next to image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am newbie on Rails 4.  I have installed paperclip gem and can successfully save images.  However, when I display image, I see the hash value displayed next to the image.  How can I get rid of the hash value?

Below are the hash value and my html code

```
> [#<Upload id: 18, project_id: 17, attachment_file_name:
> "fb_icon_325x325.png",  attachment_content_type: "image/png",
> attachment_file_size: 4822, attachment_updated_at:  "2014-01-29
> 05:53:36", created_at: "2014-01-29 05:53:38",  updated_at: "2014-01-29
> 05:53:38">]

<%= @projects.uploads.each do |u| %>
    <%= link_to image_tag(u.attachment.url(:thumb)), u.attachment.url(:original) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remove the `=` at the first line:

```
<% @projects.uploads.each do |u| %>
   <%= link_to image_tag(u.attachment.url(:thumb)), u.attachment.url(:original) %>
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps